# Voltage divider arduino 5v and Ethernet board 3.3

Tags: arduino-uno

I have an `Arduino Nano 5v` module and I just received an Ethernet Interface Board - `ENC28J60` that runs at `3.3v`. (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/765)

Might sound a dumb question but I will power the Ethernet board from a Voltage regulator that can deliver 3.3v but then I have to connect via `SPI` to my Arduino controller. I guess I can't connect my Arduino pins directly to the Ethernet board right? because HIGH in the pin will be 5v instead of 3.3v.

> Do I need to add a Voltage divider for those pins connections? And in case I need to what resistance values are the right ones to use?

Thanks

Comment: Yep, you need Bi-directional logic voltage converter https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/bi-directional-logic-level-converter-hookup-guide

Comment: @martynas those are more geared towards I2C, since I2C has a bidirectional data line.

Comment: Wooow nice!!! yes I have seen those Bi directional logic voltage converters now I know whats that for. Appreciat it

Comment: And I guess that logic voltage converters are only used for the Pins right... for powering the module then is right to use a voltage regulator such as the LM3940 IC.

Comment: Yup you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From experience with 3.3v ESP8266es with 5v Arduinos, only the signals *to* the 3.3v device need to be converted (5v high -> 3.3v high). A 3.3v level *to* the Arduino is high enough for 5v logic to still read it as HIGH. That means you can get away with just a voltage divider on each of the Arduino -> ENC28J60 pins.